# java Illegal argument exception unknown source

Tags: java

I have one web application which uses myfaces, Ajax and Javascript. I have successfully deployed it in Tomcat 6.x.

Now when I try to click one of the links in the Application it gives me "server error occurred" with the following stack trace in Tomcat logs.

I really don't understand what this error is about. But I can see it is saying it couldn't find some files in library (Unknown source).

But I have double checked and I have all the files in that jar file which it is looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
2014-08-01 13:57:10,305 [http-9999-4] ERROR com.milan.products.tchart.dao.survey.cn.RailProfileDAO - Error occured while reading for left/right profile records
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read rail profile file(s) C:\Installs\eclipse\ws\TrackIT\docroot\railprofile\049\2014050602\2014050602049.rpi C:\Installs\eclipse\ws\TrackIT\docroot\railprofile\049\2014050602\2014050602049.rpd!
at com.milan.libraries.RailProfileUtils.file.AbstractRpFile.getDataFileHeader(Unknown Source)
at com.milan.libraries.RailProfileUtils.file.AbstractRpFile.getFileVersion(Unknown Source)
at com.milan.libraries.RailProfileUtils.file.RpFileFactory.getRpFile(Unknown Source)
at com.milan.libraries.RailProfileUtils.file.RpFileFactory.getRpFile(Unknown Source)
at com.milan.products.tchart.dao.survey.cn.RailProfileDAO.getChannelData(RailProfileDAO.java:125)
at com.milan.products.tchart.channel.AbstractTrackChartChannel.getChannelData(AbstractTrackChartChannel.java:112)
at com.milan.products.tchart.composer.AbstractTrackChartComposer.populateTrackChartWithChannelFeatures(AbstractTrackChartComposer.java:90)
at com.milan.products.tchart.composer.AbstractTrackChartComposer.drawTrackChart(AbstractTrackChartComposer.java:59)
at com.milan.products.tchart.facade.TrackITTrackChartFacade.createChart(TrackITTrackChartFacade.java:225)
at com.milan.products.trackit.tchart.business.service.impl.ChartService.getCharts(ChartService.java:151)
at com.milan.products.trackit.ui.handler.XYChartImageHandler.createChart(XYChartImageHandler.java:102)
at com.milan.products.trackit.ui.handler.XYChartImageHandler.search(XYChartImageHandler.java:61)
at com.milan.products.trackit.common.ui.listener.ImageTabChangeListener.processTabChange(ImageTabChangeListener.java:55)
at org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.TabChangeEvent.processListener(TabChangeEvent.java:63)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:554)
at org.apache.myfaces.custom.tabbedpane.AbstractHtmlPanelTabbedPane.broadcast(AbstractHtmlPanelTabbedPane.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:180)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:158)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.JsfOneOneInvoker.invokeOnRegionOrRoot(JsfOneOneInvoker.java:62)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxContext.invokeOnRegionOrRoot(AjaxContext.java:176)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewRoot.processDecodes(AjaxViewRoot.java:267)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesExecutor.execute(ApplyRequestValuesExecutor.java:32)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:96)
at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.milan.products.trackit.common.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you make your jar? The server might not be looking for these files inside the jar but out in the filesystem. The path in your error isn't a relative path, but instead a specific path to a specific place on the machine.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read rail profile file(s) C:\Installs\eclipse\ws\TrackIT\docroot\railprofile\049\2014050602\2014050602049.rpi C:\Installs\eclipse\ws\TrackIT\docroot\railprofile\049\2014050602\2014050602049.rpd!
```

Also interestingly, its looking for the document inside eclipse, which I imagine is the IDE you are using. Check in your code to see if you have this path hard coded in somewhere, if it is you may want to try changing it to a relative path (something like `\TrackIT\docroot\railprofile\049\2014050602\2014050602049.rpd`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked my project and I don't even have the folder called "railprofile". So basically is it looking for the folder that contains the jar?